# SendKeys not stopping screensaver coming on

Tags: c#, windows, windows-xp, screen

I am trying to make an application which will prevent the screensaver coming on. This will have a time limit and will allow us to give users the option to prolong the screensaver during presentations/movies without us having to change the policy to allow them to disable it all together.

For this I have a C# app which sends a keypress using `SendKeys.Send("+");` every 10 seconds. However this will only disable the screensaver after it comes on, and not before. In other words, when running this I observe the screensaver to come on and then turn off after 10 seconds, even though it has been running sending keypresses before, this does not prevent the screensaver from activating.

Does anyone know what might cause this, or a way around? I have tried Windows 7, Windows XP, Restricted account and Administrator account, all has the same result.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would imagine that since it is Windows that is determining whether or not there has been *user* activity, it knows that `SendKeys()` should be ignored. Once the screensaver is up, it respond by removing it (since that's what a keypress would do.)

Comment: Most video players worth their salt already have built-in screensaver disable.

Comment: `give users the option to prolong the screensaver during presentations/movies` Powerpoint and Windows Media player already prevent the screen saver from starting when active.